fetching articles to a blog using wordpress API
My code deosn't work because of the fetching.
Hello I'm trying to fetch the articles page with the wordpress API.
<script> 
    export default {
    async asyncData({params, error, app}) {
        console.log("Fetching data for slug:", params.slug);
        const url = link_here;
        try {
            const response = await app.$axios.$get(url);
            if (!response || response.length === 0) {
                error({statusCode: 404, message: 'Article not found'});
                return {article: null};
            }
            return {article: response[0]};
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error fetching article:", e);
            error({statusCode: 500, message: 'Server error'});
            return {article: null};
        }
    }
    ,
    methods: {
        scrollToTop() {
            window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
        },
        toggleShareModal() {
            this.showShareModal = !this.showShareModal;
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            article: null,
            showShareModal: false,
            error: null
        };
    }
}
</script>

This code does print " no article found"
I can't see the mistake. Can you help me please.

Does it work with Postman?

yes it works on my browser

with postman I have this []

Huh? I do not see how you can have some results in your network tab on Nuxt's side while Postman gives you an empty result. Postman should be the one to work well first.

this is why I don't understand

Is the Wordpress API public? How do you see stuff on the dashboard while nothing in Postman? Double-check the endpoint or anything that might fail. Hard to help you without more context/details here. I also do not understand how you can have This code does print " no article found" while still a result. All of those are very confusing tbh. Maybe make a [repro] on Codesandbox to try to figure out a bit more what's going on.

Actually I'm trying to create a blog. I have modified my fetching function and I got the right data with postman but when I click on read more, the page of the article doesn't open..

read more on Postman?? More details would be welcome here. Don't you need a thing like /article/12/details?

yes I have a button on the first page of the blog that allow you to read more about the article. but when I click on it, nothing is happening. There are no error the browser's console...

What about the network tab? What about the endpoint? Postman?
